# Vagrant Up Error Operation not permitted

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am trying to install laravel/homestead however, during the installation I encountered an error with my VBoxManage when I ran the command `vagrant up`, what can I do to fix this?

- Distro: openSUSE Leap 42.1
- Vagrant version: 1.8.6
- VirtualBox version: 5.0.26_SUSE r108824

The Error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: Operation not permitted
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

Does this have anything to do with permissions? because of `Operation not permitted`?

I checked the file with `ls -l /dev/vboxnetctl` and this is what it returned:

```
crw------- 1 root root 10, 55 Oct  3 07:24 /dev/vboxnetctl
```

Should I be changing the permission of this file? If so, I want to let you know that I did it before and it still shows an error, but this error is different:

```
/home/troopy712139/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:4:in `configure': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/troopy712139/Homestead/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `vagrantfile'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `host'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:479:in `hook'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:728:in `unload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

The `VBoxManage hostonlyif create` command worked once when I ran it in root.

```
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interface 'vboxnet1' was successfully created
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems all I needed to do was make `vboxnetctl` be owned by me, and restart my computer. I also added `vboxdrv` to run on startup by running this code:

```
service vboxdrv start
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running `sudo vagrant up --provision`.

You may also want to check to make sure your paths match up in the `Homestead.yaml` file

Comment: 'sudo vagrant up --provision' is still giving me the same error. I didn't do anything to my 'Homestead.yaml' file since I am new to Homestead.

Answer (score 0):

The error around:  /dev/vboxnetctl tells you that your user doesn't have access there.

Try something line:
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers

Alvaro